# Save Columns with Header and Line names in np.savetxt python

Tags: python, numpy, save

I have an array:

```
array([[  1.,    5.,    9.,   13.,    17.,    21.,    25.],
   [ 2.,    6.,    10.,    14.,    18.,    22.,    26.],
   [  3.,    7.,    11.,   15.,    19.,    23.,    27.],
   [ 4.,    8.,    12.,   16.,    20.,    24.,    28.]])
```

I want to put Header and Line names and save in .txt extension that looks like:`

```
`      Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7                                                               
 Line1 1       5       9       13      17      21      25
 Line2 2       6       10      14      18      22      26
 Line3 3       7       11      15      19      23      27
 Line4 4       8       12      16      20      24      28
```

The problem is when I save:

`np.savetxt('data.txt', data, delimiter='\t',fmt='%.18g')
output: 1       5       9       13      17      21      25    6       10      14      18      22      26     7       11      15      19      23      27     8       12      16      20      24      28`

Comment: savetxt has a header parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj header adds a comment (`#`) character at the beginning is it possible to prevent it?

Comment: @alper, read the docs

Comment: `np.savetxt( "data.csv", data, delimiter="\t", header=names, comments="")`

Answer (score 0):

Loop at [numpy.savetxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

You can save your file using `np.savetxt('test.out', x, delimiter='\t')`, where x is your array.

However if you are working with tables (which it looks like you are doing), you should consider using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) in python. Bu using pandas you can apply column-names to a table, and indexes ("row-names" and then easily save the table to a text file.